# Freeing space by deleting older files in the /Library/Messages/Attachment folder

Tags: macos, messages, disk-space, attachments

I would like to be able to free up space on my MacMini main hard disk, and I have found that I have about 61 GB of attachments in my /Users/mlittle-macmini-20200921/Library/Messages/Attachments folder. Would I be able to free up space either by deleting older attachments, or archiving them on to a USB drive?